# Перебор всех статичных свойств статичного класса и изменение их значений

Tags: c#

В статичном классе `SiteConfig` реализован метод сохранения настроек в БД. Сами настройки представляют собой поля. Например,

```
/// <summary>
/// Базовые настройки сайта
/// </summary>
public static GeneralConfig General { get; private set; }
```

где каждый класс (в примере это `GeneralConfig`) реализует интерфейс `ISiteConfig`, в котором есть методы сохранения и загрузки данных с БД. Сам метод реализован так:

```
/// <summary>
/// Сохраняю все настройки в БД
/// </summary>
/// <param name="configService">Сервис для работы с конфигурациями</param>
/// <param name="reLoadAfterSave">Нужно ли перезагружать данные после сохранения</param>
public static void SaveAll (ConfigService configService, bool reLoadAfterSave = true)
{
    foreach (FieldInfo field in typeof(SiteConfig).GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static |
                                                             BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy))
    {
        // получаем значение поля
        object? fieldValue = field.GetValue(null);

        // если значением поля является класс, реализующий интерфейс ISiteConfig
        if (fieldValue is ISiteConfig scValue)
        {
            // - то сохраняем его значения в БД
            scValue.SaveToDataBase(configService);

            //- если нужно перезагружать значения
            if (reLoadAfterSave)
                // -- то перезагружаем
                scValue.LoadFormDataBase(configService);
        }

        field.SetValue(null, fieldValue);
    }
}
```

Вопрос: где может быть ошибка или почему не работает?

Comment: Проблемы 2: 1. Статика - настройки, особенно которые постоянно сохраняются/загружаются, это не статичные значения, они не должны постоянно висеть в памяти, они не должны быть общими на все приложение. Это не практично, не безопасно, и не оптимально в плане потребления ресурсов. Не ленитесь, и сделайте нормальные классы, а лучше, не изобретайте своих костылей и используйте готовые решения. 2. `public static GeneralConfig General { get; private set; }`  - это поле, или свойство? После того, как ответите на этот вопрос, внимание на `.GetFields()`.

Comment: Ну, первую проблему, к сожалению, не решить, так как настройки сайта должны применяться ко всему приложению и иметься к ним доступ во всех классах (в т.ч. и статичных). В них храниться базовый URL, например, чтобы формировать относительные URL. А по второму я так понимаю это getPropertues?

Comment: 1. Значит у вас изначально неверно проектируется проект. Мое дело сказать, что это неверное решение, ваше уже делать с этой информацией что угодно. Ну и повторю про готовые решения, например, `IConfiguration` и `IOptions`, вместе с DI контейнером и вот у вас уже в любом месте приложения доступно `var someSetting = options["Key"]` или вовсе `var someSetting = options.SomeValue;`, достаточно внедрить зависимость, ну а если это ASP.NET, то там это уже из коробки стоит все. 2. Ну, конечно, вы свойства получить хотите или поля? Ответ думаю очевиден.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, спасибо. Но вот насчёт IConfiguration и IOptions. Первое использую, как настройки запуска приложения, а все настройки храню в БД. Поэтому, увы не подойдут. Можно конечно использовать сервис для контроллеров и видов, но а для статики?

Comment: Вместо того, чтоб сразу говорить "не подойдет", изучили бы вопрос. `IConfiguration` позволяет настроить **любого**  поставщика данных, будь это файл, база, облачный сервер, память, да даже командная строка, все это [без проблем настраивается](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/core/extensions/custom-configuration-provider) (кстати в этой документации написано как использовать EF в качестве провайдера конфигов). Вы ведь программист, ваша задача искать, пробовать, а уже потом говорить "не подходит".

Comment: Что касается статики - еще раз повторю, ее быть не должно, но если прям так хочется, то реализуйте синглтон объект ваших `IConfiguration` и/или `IOptions` и обращайтесь к нему в статичных объектах. Но еще раз говорю, этого у вас быть не должно, советую этот участок кода переписать на нормальные классы.

Comment: Поизучал. IConfig, конечно интересный и может работать с БД, вы правы. НО он не позволяет ПРАВИТЬ настройки.

Comment: И тут вы также не очень глубоко копнули... `IConfiguration` это пластилин, который позволяет все, что может реализовать программист. Это не набор реализаций, а набор интерфейсов, которые вы можете по своему реализовать, или переписать имеющееся. Нужна запись, без проблем, добавьте, вот к примеру [реализация для JSON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/609232/how-to-save-the-updates-i-made-to-appsettings-conf), можете попробовать через кастомный провайдер сделать что-то подобное. Повторю, они могут даже с облаком работать, а вы про какие-то базовые вещи переживаете...